# Typescript, Atom plugin giving duplicate namespace definitions in typescript d.ts files

Tags: typescript, namespaces

Typescript supports namespace merging for *.ts files. The following example uses duplicates namespace in multiple *.d.ts files to limit d.ts file size:

```
File: myRoot_common_utils.d.ts

  declare namespace myRoot {
    export namespace common {
      export namespace utils {
        export function fastTrim(foo: string);
      }
    }
}

File: myRoot_common_encoders.d.ts:

declare namespace myRoot {
   export namespace common {
      export namespace encoders {
          export function toBase64(foo: string);
      }
   }
}
```

resulting in a Duplicate identifier error using the atom typescript plug-in:

```
 myRoot_common_encoders.d.ts Duplicate identifier "common".
```

Is Typescript namespace merging limited to *.ts files?  Any suggested work around?

Answer (score 0):

> Is Typescript namespace merging limited to *.ts files

No. I am unable to reproduce. You most likely have more files in the compilation context (with duplicates) or other contents in the same file that are causing this.

Comment: Thanks, your correct.  I found another declaration  "export var common: any;" within the context of the MyRoot namespace.  After removal the issue was resolved. Though not explicitly stated in most typescript online reference material, namespace merging is supported in d.ts files in addition to .ts file.